# unable to prevent newline on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

Upon saving a file, the editor adds a new line automatically. This is not wanted as it errors our CI tool (I have no control over the CI Tool).

Steps I've taken to remedy:

- Removed all extensions in case any were adding user preferences.
- Reviewed and updated user profile to prevent new line upon saving (didn't work)
- Reverted my user settings to default

Nothing seems to work. Does anyone else have this issue and was able to resolve?

Comment: What file type(s)? Does it happen if you save the file with another editor?